# Running through the external workbook with all the matching string and copy paste it to another workbook

Tags: vba, excel

Hi currently i have a code that allow me to look through an external workbook called "Active master project" and search for the column that consist "Singapore" and it appear more than once in the column. I would need a code that would help me to run through all the rows and copy all the information that consist "Singapore" in the column A to another workbook called "easy project tracker". The code i have right now does not seem to work as it only copy paste the first "Singapore" and will stop running through the whole rows to search for the rest of the rows that have "Singapore" in column A.

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim wb1 As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim copyFrom As Range
    Dim lRow As Long '<~~ Not Integer. Might give you error in higher versions of excel
    Dim strSearch As String

    Set wb1 = Application.Workbooks.Open("U:\Active Master Project .xlsm")
    Set ws1 = wb1.Worksheets("New Upcoming Projects")

    strSearch = "Singapore"
    With ws1

        '~~> Remove any filters
        .AutoFilterMode = False

        '~~> I am assuming that the names are in Col A
        '~~> if not then change A below to whatever column letter
        lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row

        With .Range("A4:A" & lRow)
            .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=*" & strSearch & "*"
            Set copyFrom = .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow
        End With

        .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With

    '~~> Destination File
    Set wb2 = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws2 = wb2.Worksheets("New Upcoming Projects")
     With ws2
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Cells) <> 0 Then
            lRow = .Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                          After:=.Range("A4"), _
                          Lookat:=xlPart, _
                          LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                          SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                          SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                          MatchCase:=False).row
        Else
            lRow = 1
        End If

       copyFrom.Copy .Rows(lRow)
    End With
End Sub
```

Above is the code that i have right now but seems not to be working to as what i wanted. Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you. :)

Comment: you dou only copy a single line. do you want to copy the whole filtered range?

Comment: I would want to copy rows of information that consist of "Singapore" in column A @psychicebola

Comment: Hope you have gone through the additional information and found it useful. If you are satisfied please tick the answer as acceptable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have preferred Auto-filter route for your question. Auto-filtered results based on criteria "Singapore" in column A are transferred temporarily to Temp Sheet in the same workbook. From Temp sheet results are transferred to new workbook. Contents of Temp sheet are cleared thereafter. Macro-file is a separate workbook.
I am appending the code below.  Also Sample files can be downloaded by you from the below mentioned links.

http://1drv.ms/1J8a3pv Active_Master_Project.xlsx

http://1drv.ms/1J8amR9 Easy_Project_Tracker.xlsx

http://1drv.ms/1J8av72Macro_File.xlsm

```
Sub Test2()
    Set x = Workbooks.Open("c:\mydir\Active_Master_Project.xlsx") 'Change dir path
    Set y = Workbooks.Open("c:\mydir\Easy_Project_Tracker.xlsx")
    Set ws3 = y.Sheets("New_Upcoming_Projects")
    Set ws1 = x.Sheets("New_Upcoming_Projects")
    Set ws2 = x.Sheets("Temp")
    Dim LastRow As Long
    ws2.UsedRange.Offset(0).ClearContents
       With ws1
         .Range("$A:$A").AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:="Singapore"
          LastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
         .Range("A1:A" & LastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Copy _
          Destination:=ws2.Range("A1")
       End With
    ws1.AutoFilterMode = False
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
    With ws2
      .Cells.Copy ws3.Cells
      .UsedRange.Offset(0).ClearContents
    End With
   x.Close
   y.Close
 End Sub
```

Comment: Is there other way if i do not use any temp sheet and just copy the information straight away from "new upcoming project" sheet in active master file and paste it to easy project tracker in the sheet called "New upcoming project" ? @skkakkar

Comment: @nabilah  your point is not clear to me . Please illustrate with an example or elaborate it further.

Comment: I have a sheet called "new upcoming projects" in active master workbook which consist of country names in column A in that sheet. While in project tracker workbook it has a sheet called "new upcoming project" which is empty. I would want a code that allow me to search "Singapore" in column A of "new upcoming projects" in active master workbook and copy paste the information to "new upcoming projects" sheet in project tracker workbook @skkakkar

Comment: @nabilah Sorry I have just got up from sleep and I did not read your earlier comment. Advanced filter copies to Active sheet only and at the maximum to the same workbook. In-fact I also wanted to do the same as you are suggesting but I could not get it through programmatically. After Internet search I could get tis possible work around. If you are able to get some clue, I would welcome it. Using Auto-filter Is an efficient way of doing things.

Comment: Alright but i am a little confuse with the code you are given. Sorry because i am not strong VBA thus i dont really understand the codes well @skkakkar

Comment: @nabilah I am going to comment it more to explain what each part is doing and upload it. Give me few minutes.

Comment: I have uploaded Macro_File with comments.txt . You can download from here <http://1drv.ms/1Kc7830>

Comment: Alright i will take a look a it later because i am using the company laptop thus could go into the link you gave. Thank you for your help! @skkakkar